# Nginx rewrites for React app with 2 HTML pages

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

so I'm building a react site using browserHistory, my current Nginx setup serves index.html for all URLs, however I have split out my admin part of the site so I need any url under /admin to server admin.html but I can;t figure it out (not a server guy!).

This is my current config, any help would be greatly appreciated!

`server {
        listen 80;
        server_name http://178.62.98.191/;
        root /www/rawnet-one-web/dist;
        index index.html index.htm;
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ $1 permanent;
        location / {
                auth_basic "Restricted";
                auth_basic_user_file /www/.htpasswd;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the examples in the [location documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), you should just have to define the `/admin/` location and serve the `/admin.html` file for any location that matches it.

```
location /admin/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /admin.html
}
```

If you want `/admin` to not have a trailing slash, you will need to hard code that location.

```
location = /admin {
  try_files /admin.html
}
```